# Нужна ли запятая перед без?

Tags: пунктуация

В Ardes косметике применяются растения, которые выращивались природным способом, без использования опасных химических веществ.

Answer (score 3):

**Запятая нужна,** обстоятельства однородные, сближенные по значению  (=экологически правильные), пауза при чтении желательна.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, **запятая нужна**, но не потому, что это однородные обстоятельства. Невозможно представить себе природный способ с использованием опасных химических веществ; "без использования опасных химических веществ" является уточнением и отделяется запятой. Смысл этой фразы: природным способом, в частности, без использования опасных химических веществ. По классификации @Sibylla это присоединение.